# Fitting arbitrary number of gaussians using scipy.optimization.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit an arbitrary number of gaussian peaks to my data. I plan on only looking at fragments of my dataset at one time; however, in each fragment I might need to try to fit anywhere from 2-10 peaks (they are not the best resolution data and I might need to try several different combinations of peaks to get the best answer). Every implementation of multipeak fitting that I have been able to find has used a fixed number of peaks and while I can certainly change the fit function by hand, I really would rather not. Here is what I have so far...

```
def fit_func(x,*params):

    N=params[0]
    center=params[1]
    amp=params[2]
    width=params[3]

    data=np.array([],dtype=float)
    data=0.

    for i in range(N):
        data=data+amp[i]*np.exp(-(x-center[i])**2/width[i]**2)
    return(data)

f = np.array([2.3,3,8.06,9.38])          # frequency guesses
a=np.array([10,6,6,3]) #amplitude guesses
w=np.array([.5,1.,1,1])# witdth guesses
N=4
x0=[N,f,a,w]

f = np.array([2.3,3,8.06,9.38])          # frequency guesses

s=spectrum/100. #Set errorbars. Dividing by a hundred is just for testing     
                  purposes

solution,covar= optimization.curve_fit(func,freq,spectrum,(x0,),s)
```

I am not surprised that this is throwing the following ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

However, I have yet to be able to find a way to do this without getting some kind of return error. Any suggestions?